# distance between 2 annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

HI..

m looking for some help regarding the Mapkit in iphone.

i've 5 annotations marked on my map,What i need to do is..i want to use two fingers,each on the annotation and the distance between these 2 annotations can be seen on map.

pinch is already available on the mapkit to zoom...so could i add this feature to the 2 finger
touch???

Is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add this feature to the 2 finger touch. Instead you create a button, and in the button action allow the user to select two annotations and then calculate the distance by getting the latitude and longitude value of the annotation.

Comment: dat's a good idea... :)

one more thing...the distance i'm getting is the perpendicular distance between the 2 annotations?? am i right???

Comment: can u plz gimme a summary how does this selecting 2 annotations and den calculating the distance works??? :-s